# Cannot start service SQLBrowser on computer '.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, service

I've an application in c# 2010 on windows 7 64bit.
I'm trying to start SQLBROWSER via this code :

```
public void Start()
{
    if (_service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running ||
        _service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)
        _service.Start();

     _service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 0));
}
```

and I create an app.manifest file to run my app as Administrator.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

and here the error when I execute my app as administrator :

Cannot start service SQLBrowser on computer '.'

Comment: can you start the service manually, from the Services console?

Comment: also, your IF condition should probably be `&&` not `||` (not that that's why your service isn't starting)

Comment: Yes I can, and I can enable it when it's desabled via code, but to start it , no !

Comment: I tried all what you said but no result !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the solution for my problem, thank you so much @user3394380 for help, here the correct code to enable and start the service :

```
// Enable the service :
// Create a .cmd file and write the code below, then launch it via a process
"SC \\" + System.Environment.MachineName + @" Config SQLBROWSER start= auto"

// Start the service :
// Call Start()
_service.Start();
```

NB : Don't enable and start the service in the same action, as I do, I enable it in Action A, and start it in Action B.

Answer (score 0):

I debug in VS 2010 started as Administrator. It works in compiled apps.

There are app.manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
      <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>

    </application>
  </compatibility>

</asmv1:assembly>
```

and code:

```
class Program
{
    static ServiceController _service = new ServiceController("SQLBROWSER");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Enable service before starting it.
        Process.Start("sc.exe", " config SQLBROWSER start=auto");
        Start();
    }

    static void Start()
    {
        if (!(_service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running || _service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending))
            _service.Start();

        _service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 0));
    }
}
```

Check MSDN article here [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739213(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739213%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: You didn't see my comments above, I said : I can enable the service when it's disabled, but con not start it.
Go disable the service and enable it via code and then start it, you'll have the same error

Comment: Sorry, I missed disabled service part.

Comment: Update: `Process.Start("sc.exe", " config SQLBROWSER start=auto");` from [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739213(v=ws.10).aspx]